# CMS Static Blocks - Custom border? (custom css for curved border)

Tags: blocks, css, static-block

I am creating a website and I am using the CMS to create static blocks then call them in a widget however I am feeling very limited in the CSS options it gives you under "edit CSS" is there a way that I can input my own css to allow for curved borders?

I can cheat and just curve my images but I am trying to make it easier for the client. So anyway to use CSS, and if so how?

Comment: why don't you just modify the /skin/frontend...style.css and add you own curved borders rather than bothering with inline CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest if you have a custom theme you can add your own border.css to be added to all pages or all cms pages if that will do and then simply use the correct classes when building your cms page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<style></style>` tags and put the CSS you want inside it while on the WYSISYG editor.

Comment: When I do that however after I click save and continue editing it deletes the code. I have nothing but an image in it removing the anchor.

Comment: Use the button Show/hide editor. Your code should be there but the editor chooses not to show it because of the tags you are using.

Comment: No sorry I mean, when I hit save, in that part it completely wipes the style formatting. And when the page reloads and I hit show/hide the code is no longer there.

Comment: Last idea, try doing the same but put the style tags when the editor is hidden.

Comment: Just stores it as text sadly. removes all special characters.